# Calling native library functions, getting java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError?

Tags: java, c++, java-native-interface, mingw, mingw-w64

So I'm trying to get [this native library here](http://jiggawatt.org/badc0de/android/#gifflen) and get it compiled and running in my Java application. Here's the error I'm receiving when attempting to run code from the native library:

```
Exception in thread: java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: package.class.Init(Ljava/lang/String;IIIII)I
    at...
Caused by: java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: package.class.Init(Ljava/lang/String;IIIII)I
    at package.class.Init(Native Method)
    at...
```

---

Here's my process.

So I've downloaded MinGW (64-bit, as I was getting yelled at if it was 32-bit) and compiled the native library like so:

```
g++ -I"D:\My Programs\Java\jdk1.7.0_67\include" -I"D:\My Programs\Java\jdk1.7.0_67\include\win32" gifflen.cpp -o gifflen.so -shared -fPIC -Wl,--kill-at
```

This gave me the **gifflen.so** file which I use like so in my Java application:

```
...
private native int Init(String gifName, int w, int h, int numColors, int quality, int frameDelay);
private native void Close();
private native int AddFrame(int[] inArray);

static
{
    System.load("D:/Desktop/gifflen4.so");
}
...
```

I'm not sure what is relevant and what isn't, but here's part of the top of **gifflen.cpp**, including the function **Init()** which is mentioned in the error above:

```
extern "C"
{
JNIEXPORT jint JNICALL Java_org_jiggawatt_giffle_Giffle_Init(JNIEnv *ioEnv, jobject ioThis, jstring gifName, jint w, jint h, jint numColors, jint quality, jint frameDelay);
JNIEXPORT void JNICALL Java_org_jiggawatt_giffle_Giffle_Close(JNIEnv *ioEnv, jobject ioThis);
JNIEXPORT jint JNICALL Java_org_jiggawatt_giffle_Giffle_AddFrame(JNIEnv *ioEnv, jobject ioThis, jintArray inArray);
};

JNIEXPORT jint JNICALL Java_org_jiggawatt_giffle_Giffle_Init(JNIEnv *ioEnv, jobject ioThis, jstring gifName, jint w, jint h, jint numColors, jint quality, jint frameDelay)
{
// code etc...
}
```

Comment: I guess your Java code is not in the right package and class. The native methods should be in `org.jiggawatt.giffle.Giffle`.

Comment: @ChristianHackl Well, when you point it out like that, it's pretty obvious, lol. That was it, it seems to work, though now the application just crashes with a fatal error "EXCEPTION_ACCESS_VIOLATION" pointing at the .so file. Oh well.

Comment: That's an entirely different error. I guess you should ask a new question for it, or research some existing SO questions. I'll make my comment into an answer for now.

Answer (score 0):

Your Java code is not in the right package and class. The native methods should be in `org.jiggawatt.giffle.Giffle`.